# Build Yii web app over fully working database

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

Is it safe to build a Yii application over a SQL Server database which is being used by another software? 
The ideia is to migrate that desktop software for a WebApp but **I must let the database structure untouched**. 
It's a quite complex database and I have very complex SQL Queries as well, so I should avoid DAO and AR. I've been looking for some information around the web but it's not clear to me how safe it will be this process. Should I build all the application with RAW SQL and be careful with it's implementation?

Can anyone of you show me the right path I should follow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would your Yii application do ? Will you need to update and create data from Yii ?

Comment: I just need to read, update and delete data. No need to create tables.

Comment: But the other software will still use that database in the same time ?

Comment: No, the software will be deactivated. But I must respect it's database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just plain SQL with Yii, have a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand

But if you want more flexibility, I can recommend you the following way.

1. create an initial database migration, just `execute()` a plain SQL dump from your exisiting database.
2. create database migrations as you need them
3. apply migrations
4. develop
5. go to step 1. if you want to test with newer data and reapply migrations to your database
6. shut down old application

As your migrations are versioned with your application, you could eg. maintain a branch with the old db-schema and work parallel on an updated version with another db-schema.

Comment: That was a huge help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely safe to do this, with Yii you can use any database structure you need. You'll only need to create your models based on your current database structure.

Here a quick guide to use Yii with SQLServer http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/192/config-use-ms-sql-server-2005-2008/

Comment: Agreed. I've done this over several apps where another app was also accessing the day and changing it. That gets a bit more complicated, but it works quite well